# Gradle (wrapper) + STS + Spring Boot: Error: Could not find or load main class 1.1,

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, spring-tool-suite, buildship

One project among many started giving me the following error when running `Gradle Tasks` -> `application` -> `bootRun`:

> Error: Could not find or load main class `1.1,`

However, the following both work:

- Running `./gradlew bootRun` from the command-line
- Starting the service with STS `Boot Dashboard`

It's odd that the Gradle Task window's execution is coming up with the class `1.1,`.

Ideas?

**Configuration**

- Windows 10 Pro
- STS 3.9.4.RELEASE
- Eclipse Buildship 2.2.1
- Gradle Wrapper 4.5.1
- Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE

**Attempts**

- Ran `./gradlew clean build`
- Refreshed `Gradle Tasks` in the window
- Right-clicked project and ran `Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project`
- Restarted STS
- Deleted `./metadata` and restarted STS
- Deleted `./bin` and `./build` directories
- Unloaded the project and re-imported as Gradle project
- Ran "STS -clean"

... always the same result

Comment: This is an old question by now. Not sure you still care, but I'll add my two cents. I don't really have much of an idea unfortunately, other than that it sounds like a bug in BuildShip more than anything. So if you want to follow up on this, it should probably be done by filing a bug-report with buildship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. Anyway in Eclipse Oxygen it just suddenly stops working but in terminal it is fine.

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/1747

Maybe this link would help. It is not working for me but I believe it points to the right direction.

Solution he purposes:

> No, removing of node does not help. But the follow line in the Gradle script solve the problem:
>
> ```
> System.getProperties().remove( 'org.osgi.framework.system.capabilities' )
> ```
>
> The value of the property is:
>
> ```
> osgi.ee; osgi.ee="OSGi/Minimum"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JRE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact1"; version:List<Version>="1.8",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact2"; version:List<Version>="1.8",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE/compact3"; version:List<Version>="1.8"
> ```
>
> It look like that you try to add all environment variable to the command line but does not quote correctly.

Comment: Can you please share the build.gradle { i am new to it :) } . I am also facing the similar issue from STS. I tried this but again STS is failing to run the project.

Comment: No I cannot. Was long time ago and I don't have access to code now. Google Groovy syntax, maybe.